# list size is incorrect in ExpandableListView when i Collapsed one group

Tags: android, expandablelistview

i have ExpandableListView and at first all item is closed . when i open one  group , my list show its child and list is correct , but when i close group , my group closed but count item in list dont change , for examle:
i have followed group ;

```
+a
+b
+c
```

and b have to 2 chid (b0,b1) 
when i open b group b :

```
+a
-b
b0
b1
+c
```

Thiat is correct , but when i close it , my list change :

```
+a
+b
+c
b1
```

That It is incorrect ;

Comment: if you are on explistview without opening any group a,b,c and you clicked directly on c. which item are you able to see?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the view to null in the ExpandListAdapter before inflating the layout in both the getGroupView and getChildView.

```
view == null;
```

Not sure what the issue is with the rest of your code, but this will reset the view every time something is changed and will keep your list from going crazy.